# Convert seconds into days and hours

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, timestamp, momentjs

How to convert 340047 seconds into days and hours duration with Moment.js?

Comment: @Spectric yes. I need to convert it into duration based on days and hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need moment.js.

You can calculate the days by dividing the seconds by `86400`.

You can calculate the hours by dividing the seconds by `3600`, then subtracting the hours in the number of days.

```js
const seconds = 340047;

const days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600) - (days  * 24);
console.log('Days:', days, 'Hours:', hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Moment.js solution:

You can use `moment#duration` to do it.

```
const moment = require("moment");

let s = 340047;
var diff = new moment.duration(s * 1000);
console.log('Days: ',Math.floor(diff.asDays()), 'Hours: ',Math.floor(diff.asHours()) % 24);
```

outputs

> Days:  3 Hours:  22